# How to maintain the page state in asp.net when autopostback = true?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can I get the same scroll position after postback? I am doing code in vb. I have referred and tried everything mentioned in following question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147942/how-to-maintain-scroll-position-on-autopostback).But nothing worked for me. How to overcome this problem?

Comment: See My Answer Posted Below

Answer (score 1):

DO

```
Page.SmartNavigation = true
```

or

```
MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback = true
```

or

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"
```

put it in pageload outside of if(!Page.IsPostBack) if using

Comment: MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" is working in IE and not in Firefox. Is there any idea to get this work in firefox?

Comment: while using first option it gives error msg as **Public Property SmartNavigation As Boolean is obsolete. The recommended alternative is Page.SetFocus() and MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback**

Answer (score 0):

MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback = "true" in page declaration should work

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `Hidden Fields`
To store Your Scroll Bar Top and Left Values Before PostBack
And then Obtain Same Value from `Hidden Fields`
after PostBack

```
function BeforePostBack()
{
// Save Scroll Bar values in Hidden fields
// ScrollLeft() and ScrollTop()
}

function afterPostBack()
{
// Get Scroll Bar values from Hidden fields
// and assign to Scroll bars

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `UpdatePanel`.

that way you do not have to refresh the entire page during postback.

only the UpdatePanel will refresh during postback.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb386454.ASPX